# How can I add !important css attribute with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I add !important css attribute with jQuery to after the "border-left-color",'#'+hex ?

```
$(document).ready(function($){
           $('.gkColorPicker').colpick({
           layout:'full',
           colorScheme:'light',
           onChange:function(hsb,hex,rgb,fromSetColor) {
           if(!fromSetColor) $('.gkColorPicker').val(hex).css("border-left-color",'#'+hex);
           },
           onSubmit:function(hsb,hex,rgb,el) {
          $('.gkColorPicker').colpickHide();
          }
         });
          $('.gkColorPicker').keyup(function(){
         $(this).colpickSetColor(this.value);
   });
});
```

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: Don’t use `!important`; fix the rest of your CSS instead.

Comment: If the answer is to use `!important`, you're asking the wrong question.

Comment: Beat me to it @minitech.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add `!important` since `.css` adds inline styles which have the highest specificity already.  Unless you are trying to override another rule already using `!important`, which gives you a good reason why you shouldn't have used it to begin with.

Answer (score -2):

Did u try sth like that:

```
$('.gkColorPicker').css("border-left-color",'#'+hex+' !important');
```

Comment: Did you try something like that?

Comment: @james montagne did you try something like that?

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, yes I try but that didn't work for me.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Did you try something like that?

Comment: sorry for my mistake,but u try add css for value! i didnt see that and i've copied that. For what u want use !important? Properties that added line-style have higher priority than css styles in file.

Comment: @minitech well, apparently I haven't, given that the score's saying i'm wrong :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak Yeah, it doesn't work.